# AWS Cognito : How to show custom attributes on the hosted sign-up UI?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito's hosted UI , I added a couple of custom attributes and assigned read write permission as well. I still cant see the custom attributes on the sign-up form.

Answer (score 2):

As of today, you can only do it for standard attributes. If you make them required they will show up on the sign-up form.

The custom attributes are always nullable and therefore do not appear on the form.

Comment: Is this feature implemented now?